# Spring-Boot Query SELECT * FROM book (MANY to MANY rel with user) doesn't work properly

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many, findall

I am trying to return all the books from my database, but once I inserted values into the join table called COLLECTION (for solving the Many-to-Many Rel between BOOK and USER) the output I am receiving looks like a loop (tested with Postman).

The implementation of Book Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Collection> collections;

    public Book(String title, String author, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.description = description; 
}

    public Book(String title, String author Collection... collections){
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;

        for (Collection collection : collections){
            collection.setBook(this);
        }
        this.collections = Stream.of(collections).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

The implementation of User Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String username;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Collection> collections = new HashSet<>();

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

The Collection Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity
public class Collection implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Book book;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private User user;

 public Collection(User user){
        this.user = user;
}
 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(this == o) return true;
        if(!(o instanceof Collection)) return false;
        Collection that = (Collection) o;
        return  Objects.equals(book.getTitle(), that.book.getTitle()) &&
                Objects.equals(book.getAuthor(), that.book.getAuthor()) &&
                Objects.equals(user.getUsername(), that.user.getUsername());
}
 @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return Objects.hash(book.getTitle(), book.getAuthor(), user.getUsername());
    }
}
```

And finally there is the BookRepository:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {
// this causes sql syntax error
//    @Query(value = "SELECT b.id, b.title, b.author FROM book b", nativeQuery =  true)
//    List<Book> getAllBooks();

// this returns the loopy output from postman detailed below 
     List<Book> findAll();
}
```

The output I receive in Postman looks like a loop:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Pride and Prejudice","author":"Jane Austen","users":[{"id":1,"email":"a@a.com","password":"$2a$10$BVXUCumzWyec9zEUeCv1r.m2pFwvAe7Cp1dLjiGfXuEEIHkhn3jHO","username":"user","books":[{"id":1,"title":"Pride and Prejudice","author":"Jane Austen", "users":[{"id":1,"email":"a@a.com","password":"$2a$10$BVXUCumzWyec9zEUeCv1r.m2pFwvAe7Cp1dLjiGfXuEEIHkhn3jHO, "username":"user","books": .......
```

The expected output should be a list of all the books I have in the database.

Comment: Please, use `@ManyToMany` annotation, not `@ManyToOne` with garbage entities. Also, don't abuse lombok annotations, don't use `@ToString` on entities, is create endless cycle of `toString()` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set relationship between book and user set the direct relationship using @ManyToMany mapping.
For reference you can prefer the following link-

https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-many-to-many-mapping-example/

Also you don't need to define findAll() explicitly,Jpa repository provides these general methods itself.

Comment: I followed the tutorial you linked me, but I have the same problem which is caused by those set collections(used for connecting the tables) that give the loopy output once these are entries in the Collection table. Before I populate the Collection table I get this kind of output for findAll().[ { "id": 1,"title": "P", "author": "A", "description": "d", **"users": []** }, ...]. After adding entries to the table, it gets loopy. From my understanding, I need an explicit Query for it since it returns the users collection which is irrelevant for me when I only want to display all the books.

Comment: check by applying FetchType.LAZY on mapped fields.By Default this is set to FetchType.Eager,this means that it fetches the all child entities along with parent and get continue on this.

Comment: I already have FetchType.LAZY. This is the code: 
``public class Book {
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JoinTable(name = "collection",
               joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "book_id") },
               inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") })
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}`` And: ``
public class User{
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
}``

Comment: Are you using converters to change entities into beans?

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by using a DTO and converting Book to BookDTO. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Converting the entity object into DTO is recommended approach.it sounds good to hear that you solved your problem.also please accept my answer if somehow it helped.
Thanks